# No custom headers when setFullResponse(true)

Tags: http, typescript, header, cors, restangular

I'm using [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular). I would like to get full response so I set

```
Restangular.setFullResponse(true);
```

but then I discovered that my custom headers does not work. Documentation for `setFullResponse()` method says:

> in order for Restangular to access custom HTTP headers, your server must respond having the Access-Control-Expose-Headers: set.

I would like to send my custom headers but I don't want to change server settings. Is it possible?
If I leave default settings i.e.`setFullResponse(false)` there is no issue with custom headers. Is there another solution except changing server settings?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you cite from the `setFullResponse()` docs is about what headers from the *response* your Restangular app will be able to access. And what that is saying is, it’s not possible to access most of the headers from the response unless the server’s already configured to send the right response-header names in the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header.

Without the server setting any value for that header, the only response headers that browsers will let you access from client-side JavaScript in your web app are the `Cache-Control`,
`Content-Language`,
`Content-Type`,
`Expires`,
`Last-Modified`
& 
`Pragma` response headers.

See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-response-header-name for the spec on that.

> I would like to send my custom headers but I don't want to change server settings. Is it possible?

If you mean you want to send custom headers in a request from your client-side Restangular code to the server, please provide more details about exactly which custom headers you want to send.

There too though, there’s another CORS header your server must send in the response: the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header. If the server isn’t configured to send that with the right header names listed, then your request will fail. The reason in that case is, you will hit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests.